# Non-rectangular TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried searching for a solution, but I couldn't find anything of the sort.

My quest is: is it possible to have a `non-rectangular TextView`? I need to put a TextView and an ImageView inside a fragment.

Would look something like this:
[image]

I was thinking of maybe having two TextViews (lets call them tv1 and tv2) and an ImageView (Img1).
I could align the tv1 to the bottom of img1 and align the top of tv2 with img1. SOMEHOW play with the text in the TextViews to split it in both TextViews?

Comment: What if you used a WebView, and put some HTML in it? Easier, indeed!

Comment: Fantasy, man... use your imagination! Someone wiser than me said: dream, be mad (or something like that). ;)

Comment: @ArtooDetoo fantasy often leads to bad code. If there was a way, it would have been much better to use TextView.

Comment: @Doctoror Drive: Let me disagree... Fantasy is a MUST. Without it, you wouldn't have creativity. One that fantasy suggested you something, then you must apply method and study to pursue your goals. I don't think that method and sudy (research and development) lead to bad code. If you know how to code! That's the point, in my opinion. I agree that a TextView is somehow limited, but using a WebView is far simpler than creating a custom TextView, don't you?

Comment: @ArtooDetoo I pursue using the most efficient and simplest way instead of coding "fantasy code". TextView is much more efficient in performance than WebView. One must search for a solution using simpler APIs. Because of fantasy we have so much questions like trying to replace windows using window manager instead of using PopupWindow etc, using vertical LinearLayouts in ScrollView instead of ListView, using ImageView + TextView instead of TextView and compound drawables, creating custom TextViews instead of using Spannable. That's how I see "fantasy" term.

Comment: @Doctoror Drive: It's your opinion. I don't share it, but I respect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow textview will help to acheive what you want. Here are the few links

http://grishma102.blogspot.in/2013/12/how-to-make-text-flow-around-images-in.html

https://code.google.com/p/android-flowtextview/

Comment: Cool thanks! I'll try this out later as I don't like using WebViews either

Comment: Still didn't get the time to test this out (midterms coming soon!) :( Will have to try on Monday!