# How to achieve this textview Alignment with image in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to achieve similar following alignment in Android text view with image. Is there a way around this?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bReaA.png)

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801525/non-rectangular-textview

Comment: Please do not add invalid tags with question . you can't be using all these at once Css kotlin and html .

Comment: @TylerQI thanks for the link. I have tried the solution, it is working with LeadingMarginSpan. But I want in opposite way, I am not able to achieve the need(the image to be at the Rightside). So, please help me to solve this issue.